# How does one set the time interval for a background agent to run in a windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I can't seem to find this basic information about Windows Phone background agents - how does one actually set what the time interval is for them to run?

Whether a scheduled task or a resource intensive task, the only place I see anything related to time intervals is when it's called as a test in the debugger:

```
// If debugging is enabled, launch the agent again in one minute.
#if DEBUG_AGENT
  ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
```

...but I don't actually see where the regular, release-build equivalent of this is.

Can the background agent be scheduled this way for a release build?

Comment: You can't, it's always ~28 minutes

Comment: Yes, since I posted this question, Microsoft updated the doc page with a paragraph explaining that.  Thank you!